# Removing the desired access from the pre operation routine in kernel mode, leaves the process in eternal suspension

Tags: c++, windows-kernel

I am new to kernel and c++ development, but I am trying to develop a handler test in which the `PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME` flag of `OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess` can be removed in the pre-operation routine for a specific process `(notepad.exe )`

```
if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE) 
{

        OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~0x0001;
        OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~0x0800;

        KdPrint(("[OperationInformation->Operation]: OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE\r\n"));
}
```

I can remove the flag 0x0001 which is `PROCESS_TERMINATE` and 0x0800 which is `PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME` but when the process is created it stays suspended forever.
My goal for the test is to run notepad.exe normally and prevent the process from being suspended or terminated.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on the host computer.
The physical target PC and host are running Windows 10 1909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution. Simply run notepad.exe and then instruct kernel driver to remove these flag (0x0800). Notepad.exe could not be suspended or resumed